# Why aren't JBoss System Properties configured via the SystemPropertiesService working inside a sar/META.INF/jboss-service.xml

Tags: java, jboss, properties, jboss5.x

On JBoss 5.0.1 I have configured the deploy/properties-service.xml to reference a properties file like this...

`<attribute name="URLList">
      ${jboss.server.config.url}myconfig.properties 
    </attribute>`

The properties that are configured in the myconfig.properties file work some files (ex: deploy/postgres-ds.xml).  But the properties are not properly substituted within a deploy/my.sar/META-INF/jboss-service.xml

I also tried adding the properties to the properties-service.xml like so

`<attribute name="Properties">
      my.property=value
    </attribute>`

which doesn't work.

But if I add -Dmy.property=value in the run.conf the property IS substituted in the jboss-service.  Any one have any suggestions?

Comment: Also having this issue. ever find a sol'n?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your `my.sar` get's loaded before `properties-service.xml`.
Try to add mbean-dependency for the first on the second.

There is also a `-p` command line option for jboss to load *.properties file on early startup.

Comment: Thanks.  I tried adding the following dependency to my mbean definition but that didn't change things `<depends>jboss:service=SystemProperties</depends>`  Using `--properties` on startup does work and I'll play with getting that working but I would much rather be able to control the configuration from something other than a run parameter.  It doesn't feel like a nice solution to me.  Any other things I might try?

Comment: You could reference the same myconfig.properties file both in properties-service.xml and with --properties param on startup. )

Comment: I'm trying to reduce the jboss customization points.  I have it working using --properties and that'll have to stick for now.  I'll try again when we upgrade to jboss7.  Thanks for your help.